# Getting the output but also getting undefined first in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I have a dropdown and when it's changed then I am calling the ajax depending upon the dropdown value. If the dropdown `value` is `2` then it will call the ajax and display the data.

Now my issue is, 1) I am getting the output but also i am getting undefined.

[image]

2) After getting the output I have to display inside if-else condition but it's only displaying `undefined`.

**Controller**

```
public function getRMname(){
  $result= $this->Employee_model->getRMname();
  if($result)
    {
      foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
              $data[] = array('rmfirstname' =>$value->firstname , 'rmlastname'=>$value->lastname,'rmid'=>$value->id);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $data = "false"; 
    } 
       echo json_encode($data); 
   }
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on('change', '.pp_Status', function(event) {
  var addrm;
  if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/getRMname",
      //data: {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        addrm += '<select name="addrm" class="input-wrapper"><option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>';
        $.each(response, function(key, data) {
          addrm += '<option value="' + data.rmid + '">' + data.rmfirstname + ' ' + data.rmlastname + '</option>';
        });
        addrm += '</select>';

      }
    });
  } else {
    addrm = '';
  }
  if (somecondition) {

} else {
 echo addrm;
    //displaying addrm variable here
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show what are you getting in `response`?

Comment: @RamSegev, I am getting [object Object],[object Object] because of muttiple data

Comment: try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: @RamSegev My output is, [{"rmfirstname":"qwer","rmlastname":"qwedfg","rmid":"16"},{"rmfirstname":"mnbhg","rmlastname":"kjhgf","rmid":"10"}]

Comment: use this var addrm='';

Comment: @KUMAR, I already defined var addrm. Where should I add?

Comment: @KUMAR, Yes, my undefined issue got resolved after using var addrm = '';

Comment: @questionbank can you get data `<select>` option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be on the safe side, define the variable as
    var addrm = '';

Take out the else state so it only runs when selected option is 2.

Finally, the block which checks if selected option is 2 gets executed irrespective of the selected option because you aren't targeting properly.

It should be:

```
if( $(this).find(':selected').val() == '2' ) {}
```

Because what you have there doesn't check for the selected value, try console logging to check the value returned:

```
 console.log($(this).find(':selected').val());
```

Comment: @SundyJohnson, May I know why use var addrm = ''; because it's solved my first issue.

Comment: Defining variables with just var leaves them undefined so unless you explicitly give them a value they will return undefined. Generally, your code could have ran successfully but like I explained, the else statement wasn't getting executed because you weren't checking for the value of the selected option.

Comment: What's the second issue?

Comment: My second issue is, I have to display the addrm output in the second if condition.

Comment: If you are referring to the if(somecondition) block then put it in the success: function (response){} callback function. Any questions?

Comment: I can't use the inside success function because I have to display outside of the ajax. I have to display select inside else which code I added in the question.

Comment: async: false solved my second issue. I have to display the output of the variable outside of the ajax.

Answer (score 1):

use `='';` in defing variable

`var addrm='';` instead of

```
var addrm;
```

beacause **Variable** means anything that can `vary`, you should have to first declare `empty String` and then after String Concatenate with `+=` symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KUMAR, It's helped me to solve my first issue. upvote from my side.